# How to login to remote host when home directory is 777ed

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, user-permissions

I did ssh into a remote Ubuntu host (Amazon EC2 instance), then set 777 permission for /home/user. After sometime the connection got closed. Now when I try to do ssh, I get error message **Permission denied (publickey)**. How can I login again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- stop current instance and launch another instance with similar AMI and in the same zone.
- detach disk volume from old instance and mount to new instance.
- in the new instance, change the required file permissions inside the newly mounted volume
- detach volume from new instance and attach to old instance.

Then I was able to SSH. Steps mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingMindTerm) in detail